# pandas Dataframe.hist histogram, seaborn style

Tags: python, pandas, histogram, seaborn

I have a Dataframe, i.e.

```
df = pd.DataFrame([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10])
```

Using hist() produces e.g.:

```
df.hist()
```

[image]

This is accurate but not visually pleasant and although it can be improved, e.g.

```
df.hist(ec='black')
```

[image]

It is far to what [seaborn](http://seaborn.pydata.org/tutorial/distributions.html) would provide by default (edit: Seaborn seems to do interpolation and to give a line describing the distribution for the histogram as well.). On the other hand, seaborn by default does not give me the "right" (=what i would like/expect ;)) no of bins and y-axis e.g.:

```
import seaborn as sns
sns.distplot(df.values);
plt.show()
```

[image]

Is there any way to have panda's hist command reproduce seaborn's style in pandas?

Comment: Maybe you should be more specific about what aspect of the seaborn plot you are trying to replicate?

Comment: Sorry: Seaborn seems to do some interpolation and to give a line describing the distribution for the histogram.

Comment: Sounds like you would be well served by reading the [seaborn tutorial](http://seaborn.pydata.org/tutorial/distributions.html#plotting-univariate-distributions).